# Requests dispatch to specific JBoss instance in cluster with apache mod_cluster 1.1?

Tags: apache, jboss, load-balancing, mod-cluster

I am trying to implement JBoss AS7 clustered environment with mod_cluster as load-balancer. Can anyone explain how to dispatch requests based on URL params to specific JBoss Node using mod_cluster?

Answer (score 0):

could you elaborate more on what do you actually need to achieve?
mod_cluster is a smart load balancer that dynamically registers worker nodes and their contexts, so, for instance, if I had this cluster:

```
worker_0, contexts: houby/, ocet/, houbyaocet/
worker_1, contexts: houby/, ocet/, devtest/
worker_2, contexts: houby/, ocet/, devtest/
```

and this mod_cluster httpd load balancer:

```
http://mycompany.example.com
```

then requests to either `houby/` or `ocet/` could be balanced among all workers, whereas `devtest/` could be handled by `worker_1` and `worker_2` only. Any request to `houbyocet/` will end up on `worker_0`, because that is the only worker that registered this context.

You don't configure this whole logic, it's done automatically by mod_cluster. Worker nodes send special configuration messages to the balancer regarding which applications they have deployed, whether they are overloaded or not, whether tehy are shutting down/undeploying..etc.

HTH

Karm